# angularjs firebase storage getDownloadURL returns undefined however it exists

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-storage

Why the output for console log inside is different from console log outside? 
whereas they should both be the same.
 What I am looking for is to get the url for the file stored in the firebase storage.

```
        var url = spaceRef.getDownloadURL()
            .then(function(url){
                //$scope.avatar = url;
                console.log("inside:", url);
                return url;
                //console.log(url);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                $scope.errMsg = true;
                $scope.errorMessage = error.message;
            });
        console.log("outside:", url);
```

Answer (score 0):

`then` is a function related to Promise in javascript. Only after the getDownloadURL() is evaluated you get the output set to url variable. So inside will print the content only after the promise is evaluated and the one outside logged as as either undefined or null or empty...It's asynchronous..So the difference..

[Promis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise),
[then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)